# Notification doesn't appear android

Tags: android, notifications, calendar, android-notifications

I have a calendar library I grabbed off of github:
https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

And I'm having the user click on a date and add a reminder for that date, an alert dialog then pops up and asks them to enter the time they would like to be reminded on that day.

Now I was able to convert the text into a simpledate format and I spit it out into a string from a calendar object, so the date and time should be passing through the notification. But it doesn't seem to work anyways

Heres the code that sets the alarm:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
            notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getService(context, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            try {
                cal.setTime(alertFormatter.parse(date));
                System.out.print("Date added successfully");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to add date");
            }
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(hour.getText().toString()));
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minute.getText().toString()));
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            if(spAMpm.getSelectedItem().equals("AM"))cal.add(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
            else if (spAMpm.getSelectedItem().equals("PM"))cal.add(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);


            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
```

Then the receiver I created to do what I need it to do:

```
public class UpcomingWorkNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, UpcomingWork.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(UpcomingWork.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Four.oh")
            .setContentText("Assignment Due Soon!")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

}
}
```

In the manifest I gave it this permission and added the receiver

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

 <receiver android:name=".UpcomingWorkNotification">
    <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</receiver>
```

Even with all that the notification still doesn't appear when I set it
Can anyone help?
And thank you

Comment: Try using an implicit Intent to your broadcast receiver instead?

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't seem to be making a difference